# Mongoose - How to query field in the last object of an array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have MongoDB documents structured like this:

```json
{
    "_id": "5d8b987f9f8b9f9c8c8b9f9",
    "targetsList": [
        {
            "target": "user",
            "statusList": [
                {
                    "date": "2018-01-01",
                    "type": "OK"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2018-01-02",
                    "type": "FAILD"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And I want to count all documents that in their **"targetList"** array, there is an object with **"target"=="user"** - and also that object conatin on the **last** element of its **"statusList"** array, an object with **"type" != "FAILD"**.

Any ideas on how to implement this kind of query?

**Mongo playground:**
https://mongoplayground.net/p/3bCoHRnh-KQ
In this example, I expected the count to be 1, because only the second object meets the conditions.

Comment: can you share a sample dataset maybe using mongoplayground.net. the result you want is also not very clear

Comment: @cmgchess Thanks for the feedback, I added a playground.

Comment: so if the array has at least 1 FAILD it should count? or does it have to be last element in array

Comment: @cmgchess only if the **last** element in the internal array ("statusList") is **not** FAILD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An aggregation pipeline
**1st step** - Filtering out where `"targetsList.target": "user"`
**2nd step** - `$unwind` on `targetsList` to get it out of array
**3rd step** - getting the last element of the `targetsList.statusList` array using `$arrayElemAt`
**4th step** - getting the results where that last element is not FAILD
**5th step** - getting the count

[demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uwyZuSuuZka) - you can try removing parts of the pipeline to see what the intermediate results are

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "targetsList.target": "user"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$targetsList"
  },
  {
    $project: {
      "targetsList.statusList": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$targetsList.statusList",
          -1
        ]
      },
      
    }
  },
  {
    $match: {
      "targetsList.statusList.type": {
        $ne: "FAILD"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $count: "withoutFailedInLastElemCount"
  }
])
```

Comment: Thank you. but I just found out this solution is not accurate. 
https://mongoplayground.net/p/7tJIEZ7693M
Here you can see that it’s also counts element with “target == admin” if the same “targetList” is also contain target “user”. (See example in the second element).
And we need to count only elements with “target == user”.

Comment: @dev3dev i added size 1 to the first match. are you looking for something like https://mongoplayground.net/p/LkuDvh_5cnK

Comment: Now the query is only looking for a "targetLis" **with the size of 1**. What I need instead is that it will also look at "targetList" **with multiply targets** (like the second document there), but it will only 
 count the target "user" and will ignore other targets. Here for example, the count result should be 1: mongoplayground.net/p/LkuDvh_5cnK

Comment: https://mongoplayground.net/p/eRbI0gArOnM check with this. i brought the unwind to the front so it first seperates into individual objects and then matched users

Comment: but now if targetlist has two users with no FAILD it will count as 2. is that what you want or?

Comment: Yes. if the "targetlist" has two users it should count it twice, but avoid counting other targets such as "admin".

Comment: can you test with the last playground i commented

Comment: Perfect. that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Unless it's crucial that the element be the last index, this should work for your case.

```
db.collection.find({
  "targetsList.statusList.type": {
    $in: [
      "FAILD"
    ]
  }
})
```

This will retrieve documents where the `type` value is `FAILD`. To invert this you can swap `$in` for `$nin`.

Updated playground [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6yZFMlGLEBD)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to know if it's **in**, I want to know if it's in the **last** element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it with a leading monster "$match".

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "targetsList.target": "user",
      "$expr": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$targetsList",
          "initialValue": false,
          "in": {
            "$or": [
              "$$value",
              {
                "$ne": [
                  {
                    "$last": "$$this.statusList.type"
                  },
                  "FAILD"
                ]
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$count": "noFailedLastCount"
  }
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/vRzKIycPass).